# Mute/silence non-speech part of audio with Python (Voice Activity Detection)

Tags: python, voice-recognition, audio-processing

My purpose is to silence all the parts of a .wav audio where there is no speech. I am currently using webrtcvad, but what I achieve is just removing the non-speech part from the audio (with their example.py code: https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad/blob/master/example.py). If someone can point me or show me a how to achieve my goal, I would be grateful! This sounds also sounds like a background noise removal problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the WAV output to have the same duration as the input, just with the non-speech areas being replaced with silence, and the speech areas unaltered.

The way to do this is to multiply the audio signal with the output from the detector. The detector should output 1.0 for passing though (speech signal), and 0.0 for silencing (non-speech).

Sometimes one uses a small value instead of 0.0 for the blocking part, to just reduce the volume a bit, without making it pure silence. For example 0.01 (-20 dB).

Sometimes an abrupt transition can be a bit rough. In this case one may apply a bit of smoothing or fade. A simple alternative is an exponential moving average.

Below is complete example code in Python that implements this, using the pretrained [vad-crdnn-libriparty](https://huggingface.co/speechbrain/vad-crdnn-libriparty) model from SpeechBrain project.

The code can also be found in this Github repo: https://github.com/jonnor/machinehearing/blob/master/handson/voice-activity-detection/supress.py

```
import math
import numpy
import pandas
import librosa
import soundfile
from speechbrain.pretrained import VAD
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def detect_voice(
    path,
    activation_threshold = 0.70,
    deactivation_threshold = 0.25,
    min_pause = 0.200,
    min_activation = 0.100,
    save_dir = 'model_dir',
    segment_pre = 0.0,
    segment_post = 0.0,
    double_check_threshold = None,
    parallel_chunks = 4,
    chunk_size = 1.0,
    overlap_chunks = True,
    ):

    # do initial, coarse-detection
    vad = VAD.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/vad-crdnn-libriparty", savedir=save_dir)

    probabilities = vad.get_speech_prob_file(path,
        large_chunk_size=chunk_size*parallel_chunks,
        small_chunk_size=chunk_size,
        overlap_small_chunk=overlap_chunks)

    thresholded = vad.apply_threshold(probabilities,
        activation_th=activation_threshold,
        deactivation_th=deactivation_threshold).float()

    boundaries = vad.get_boundaries(thresholded)

    # refine boundaries using energy-based VAD
    boundaries = vad.energy_VAD(path, boundaries,
            activation_th=activation_threshold,
            deactivation_th=deactivation_threshold)

    # post-process to clean up
    if min_pause is not None:
        boundaries = vad.merge_close_segments(boundaries, close_th=min_pause)

    if min_activation is not None:
        boundaries = vad.remove_short_segments(boundaries, len_th=min_activation)

    if double_check_threshold:
        boundaries = vad.double_check_speech_segments(boundaries, speech_th=double_check_threshold)

    # convert to friendly pandas DataFrames with time info 
    events = pandas.DataFrame(boundaries, columns=['start', 'end'])
    events['class'] = 'speech'

    p = numpy.squeeze(probabilities)
    times = pandas.Series(numpy.arange(0, len(p)) * vad.time_resolution, name='time')
    p = pandas.DataFrame(p, columns=['speech'], index=times)

    return p, events



def apply_gain(path, segments, default=0.0, out=None, sr=None):

    audio, sr = soundfile.read(path, always_2d=True)

    # compute gain curves
    gains = numpy.full_like(audio, librosa.db_to_power(default)) 

    for idx, seg in segments.iterrows():

        s = math.floor(sr * seg['start'])
        e = math.ceil(sr * seg['end'])
        gain = librosa.db_to_power(seg['gain'])

        gains[s:e, :] = gain

    # apply to audio
    audio = audio * gains

    if out is not None:
        soundfile.write(out, audio, samplerate=sr)


    return audio, sr


def plot_spectrogram(ax, path, sr=16000, hop_length=1024):

    audio, sr = librosa.load(path, sr=sr)
    S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=audio, sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length)
    S_db = librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=numpy.max)

    librosa.display.specshow(ax=ax, data=S_db,
            sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length,
            x_axis='time', y_axis='mel')

    return S_db

def plot_vad(input_path, probabilities, boundaries, output_path):

    fig, (input_spec_ax, vad_ax, output_spec_ax) = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(10, 5), sharex=True)

    # show spectrogram
    plot_spectrogram(ax=input_spec_ax, path=input_path)


    # show VAD results
    probabilities.reset_index().plot(ax=vad_ax, x='time', y='speech')

    for start, end in zip(boundaries['start'], boundaries['end']):
        vad_ax.axvspan(start, end, alpha=0.3, color='green')

    vad_ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(1.0))
    vad_ax.grid(True, which='minor', axis='x')
    vad_ax.grid(True, which='major', axis='x')

    # show modified audio
    plot_spectrogram(ax=output_spec_ax, path=output_path)


    fig.tight_layout()
    return fig


# XXX: model only supports 16k samplerate
# If input is another samplerate, have to resample it first
path = 'voiceandnot_16k.wav'
prob, segments = detect_voice(path)

segments['gain'] = 0.0

out_path = 'voice-supressed.wav'
apply_gain(path, segments, default=-20.0, out=out_path)

fig = plot_vad(path, prob, segments, out_path)
fig.savefig('vad-output.png')
```

Here is an example plot, showing the input data, the VAD activations/segments and the modified output data.

[image]

Comment: I want to do exactly this. Could you elaborate a bit more on how to do it? The detector in the above repository just create multiple audio files of speech. What I did is, create a bytearray of the whole speech (instead of breaking it into pieces), and I would like to put the silence in this bytearray. How could I do that?

Comment: I also asked similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275875/python-silence-specific-part-of-audio-file , but the answer that was given was giving me wrong result.

Comment: The detector part in the above example gives a binary result is_speech, which you can convert to 1 and 0, and then follow above procedure

Comment: So the byte signal is the byte array. How can I multiply a byte array with a sequence of 0s and 1s?

Comment: The audio signal should be represented as floating point, with samplerate samples per second. If you have byte array with int16t audio data convert it to floats first. Then you can multiply

Comment: Have you considered Silero library? https://pytorch.org/hub/snakers4_silero-models_stt/