# Python silence specific part of audio file

Tags: python, audio, audio-processing, pydub, audio-analysis

I have an audio file `audio.wav` and I have an array of time frames looking like this one:

`X = [(12.31, 14.), (15.4, 18.9), ...]`

These are the time frames that I would like to be completely silent in a .wav audio file that I have. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This post may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757852/adding-silent-frame-to-wav-file-using-python It shows how to create a audio frame of duration n that is silent. But how can I plug them in the dataframes that I have?

Comment: you should add your comment to question. More people will see it. What `DataFrame` do you mean? If you mean list `X` then maybe you should use it to cut wav to create parts with sound and join with parts with silence. `song[0:12310] + silence_long_14000_minus_12310 + song[14000:15400] + silence_long_18900_minus_15400 + ...` - See `slice` in documentation [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)

Comment: eventually you can try to replace `song[12310:14000] = silence_long_14000_minus_12310` and `song[15400:18900] = silence_long_18900_minus_15400`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your link I see it as

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

a = AudioSegment.from_wav("audio.wav")

# X = [(12.31, 14.), (15.4, 18.9), ...]

duration = (14.0 - 12.31) * 1000
s1 = AudioSegment.silent(duration)

duration = (18.9 - 15.4) * 1000
s2 = AudioSegment.silent(duration)

b = a[:12310] + s1 + a[14000:15400] + s2 + a[18900:]

b.export('new_audio.wav', format='wav')
```

now problem is to use `for`-loop to automate it

I can't test it but I see it as

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

a = AudioSegment.from_wav("audio.wav")

X = [(12.31, 14.), (15.4, 18.9)]

parts = []

# start for audio
begin = 0

for start, end in X:
    # keep sound before silence
    s = a[begin*1000:start*1000]
    parts.append(s)  
    
    # create silence
    duration = (end - start) * 1000
    s = AudioSegment.silent(duration)
    parts.append(s)

    # value for next loop
    begin = end

# keep part after last silence
parts.append(a[begin*1000:])

# join all parts using standard `sum()` but it need `parts[0]` as start value   
b = sum(parts[1:], parts[0])

# save it
b.export('new_audio.wav', format='wav')
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a bit of a problem, some of the original audio is lost using this method.

Comment: Indeed, this method is losing and changing the audio for some reason. Not sure why...

Comment: I don't have your file and full `X`. Maybe you use wrong values in `X`. You would have to create new question on new page and add example `audio.wav` which you use, `new_audio.wav` which you get and manually created file which you expect.